# Visual Studio 2012 ClickOnce publishing default webpage

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, html, publish

I am publishing applications to my website using the ClickOnce publishing tool within Visual Studio 2012, which publishes the webpage which checks for prerequisites and then downloads the application. However, this is formatted completely differently to my website.

Is there a way I can pass Visual Studio a template of some sort which it can use to create the webpages, as otherwise I have to go through and manually change all of the stylings for every application/update I publish. I know I can use an external CSS file to do this, but the webpages are created with inline styling, which was causing problems with the way it was laid out when I tried this last night.

I found this from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5befhe3.aspx:

> To customize the publish Web page
>
> 1.
>   Publish your ClickOnce application to a Web location. For more information, see How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard.
>
> 2.
>   On the Web server, open the Publish.htm file in Visual Web Designer or another HTML editor.
>
> 3.
>   Customize the page as desired and save it.
>
> 4.
>   Optional. To prevent Visual Studio from overwriting your customized publish Web page, uncheck Automatically generate deployment web page after every publish in the Publish Options dialog box. For more information, see Publish Options Dialog Box.

Which means I would have to change each page manually. Does anyone know of a way to pass a template in for VS to use, or is each webpage created on the fly when I click publish?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Optional. To prevent Visual Studio from overwriting your customized publish Web page, 
>   uncheck Automatically generate deployment web page after every publish in the Publish 
>   Options dialog box. For more information, see Publish Options Dialog Box.

This is what you want to do, I guess?

Comment: That is kind of what I want to do, but for each new software I create, the default webpage will be uploaded. I can tick that box so it doesn't overwrite, but even with this option selected, I still have to manually change the pages each time I upload new software.